# Php Get data from csv to html template

Tags: php, html, csv

i'm here to get data from csv.
I hope u doing great with these corona virus.

I have a problem to solve, i want to get data from my csv file to put these into a tpl file and create a multiple html file.
i do this to get data from a line of my csv file and put this dynamically on my html template.
It worked but now i want to work with a file who contains my data on columns but i'm not an expert on Php and i don't know how to do this. can anyone help me i'm really stuck.
Here my code

```
<?php

$file = 'data.csv'; //chemin vers le fichier csv
$tpl = 'html.tpl'; //chemin vers le fichier template
$row = 1; //compteur de ligne
$tabData = array(); //tableau des données CSV
$tabTitle = array(); //titre les colonnes
$fileExt = '.html';

//ouvre le fichier
if (($handle = fopen($file, "r")) !== FALSE) {

        // on parcours le fichier csv tant qu'il n'y a plus de ligne
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data); //nombre de champs sur une ligne
                //récupère les champs sur une ligne
                for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                        if($row == 1){ // titre des colonnes csv
                         
                                $tabData[trim($data[$c])] = array(); //on créer un tableau avec le titre de la colonne
                                $tabTitle[$c] = trim($data[$c]);
                        }
                        else{
                                
                                $tabData[$tabTitle[$c]][] = trim($data[$c]); // on met les données dans le tableau
                        
                        }                               
                }       
                $row++; // on incrémente la ligne
    }           
                
                
        //récupère le fichier template
        $tplFile = file_get_contents($tpl);//récupère le fichier template
    
    $row = $row-2; //décrémente de 2 ( titre + incrément de fin en trop)
    
    //boucle sur le nombre de ligne == nombre de fichier à créer
    for($i=1;$i<$row;$i++){
      
      $tplFileTmp = $tplFile; // on associe un tpl clean
      $datas = getLine($tabData,$i);//récupère les champs de la ligne $i (1 2 3 ...)

      //boucle sur les champs pour remplacer dans le fichier tpl
      foreach($datas as $title=>$value){
          //remplace dans le tpl
          $tplFileTmp = str_replace('{'.$title.'}',$value,$tplFileTmp);
      }
      
                        // écrire le fichier
      file_put_contents($datas['productname'].$fileExt,$tplFileTmp);
      echo $datas['productname'].$fileExt." créer !<br />\n";
      
    }   

}
else{

        die("no file to open");
}

//function sinon
function getLine($array,$num){

        $ligne = $num-1;
        $tmp = array(); //tableau
        foreach($array as $title=>$tab){ //pour chaque titre=>valeur du tableau
        
                $tmp[$title]=$tab[$ligne]; 
        }
        return $tmp;
}



?>


Template html :
<section>
<div>{productname}</div>
{productdescription} 
</section>
```

Comment: "but now i want to work with a file who contains my data on columns"

What do you mean by this?

Comment: It's mean before i concatener my data on one rows and now i want to work with my data separate on columns like an normal excel sheet, thank for u repply

Comment: If you want to have addressable columns I would read the csv file and insert each record into a MySQL table that has the columns that you need. Then you can work with your columns and do anything that SQL permits you to do.

Comment: It's good it's finally worked for me, thank for ur help